# How to store additional data in SVG?

Tags: svg, svg.js

I have a small editor that creates .svg files with diagrams (using [svg.js](http://svgjs.com)).

The editor stores data about how the file created in its own simple text format, not unlike [this one](http://bramp.github.io/js-sequence-diagrams/).

I would like to embed the source text directly in the SVG file, so I can load it back without losing any metainformation user specified (like comments and formatting).

What is the proper way to do that? The editor I linked above stores its data in the `<source>` tag right under `<svg>`. Is this a good and standards-compliant approach?

```
<svg 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
  width="445" height="319" 
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
>
  <source><![CDATA[Andrew->China: Says Hello
  Note right of China: China thinks\nabout it
  China-->Andrew: How are you?
  Andrew->>China: I am good thanks!]]></source>
  <!-- SVG content here -->
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create [a custom namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071948/set-up-my-own-xml-namespace) and store whatever you want under elements in that custom namespace. You can call the custom namespace element source if you want.

Wrapping your custom content in a `<metadata>` tag is [recommended in the SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#MetadataElement). Thanks to Alexander Gladysh for reminding me of that.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a standard namespace I can reuse for my needs?

Comment: Of course not, it's your editor and your format of metadata. For example, Inkscape uses sodipodi because it started as a fork of sodipodi.

Comment: I thought that, since I store my data as plain text, there could be something reusable (similar to the `<source>` tag editor I linked to in the question uses). But OK, nevermind.

Comment: The link for the `<metadata>` tag doesn't work any more.

Comment: @RobertLongson  I expected the link to go to some part of the SVG specification, but link goes to a page that says that the metadata chapter that is no longer part of the SVG specification.

Comment: @Bernard And also has a link to where metadata has moved to. I've fixed the link to point directly to the new location.